# White screen on the frond and the back end of my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

my website shows a white screen in the frond and in backend, the only changes that i made, was some updates yesterday , i tried to restore from the bluehost but it is the same issue, in the error log it shows this error:

> [28-Aug-2018 07:10:16 UTC] [28-Aug-2018 07:10:16 UTC] The
>   WC_Cart::get_cart_url function is deprecated since version 2.5.
>   Replace with wc_get_cart_url. [28-Aug-2018 07:10:16 UTC]
>   add_to_cart_fragments is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use
>   woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments instead.

what can i do to fix it, i sell bags and this days, many people are buying from my website

Comment: Welcome to Stackoveflow, the error message seems to tell you what the prolbem is, you are using an deprecated (old) version of a method and should replace it. Can you specify where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

A plugin may be causing this. Have you tried deactivating all of your plugins? If you can't get into your site, you could do this through the server and deactivate them one by one to figure out if a particular one is causing this.

Although it seems that the function '$link = wc_get_cart_url();' is now deprecated so you can try changing this to '$link = function_exists( 'wc_get_cart_url' ) ? wc_get_cart_url() : $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();' in this file /config-woocommerce/config.php

Alternatively, you can check other solutions [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors).

Comment: I completely agree with this, white screen of death is nearly always plug ins (or theme).